# Up rest feed data

Tags: jawbone

Having to look to all the feed data in the phone harms people's necks. A more comfortable way to see and manipulate it is needed. I would like to do a web viewer to view the up application feed in a browser.

However, I had a look at the REST API and couldn't find a way to obtain it. There is a part where generic "events" are mention. Can I obtain the feed data from there?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer REST APIs do not provide the ability to re-create the UP app's feed.

If you really want to, you could do a close approximation since the APIs provide most of the data that appears in the feed. However, you would have to provide all the styling and assets yourself.

Comment: Since the most lengthy messages would be the ones that will give the higher value I'm mostly interested in Smart Coach messages. Are those provided by the API.

Comment: Sorry, SmartCoach is not available through the API at this time.